# Helm template, command

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

i want to pass two arguments to the to "deployment template" from the values.yaml the result should be like this :
[image]

in values.yaml i have this   >>>
[image]

And here is my template deployment file :

```
{{ if .Values.containerCommand }}
      command: [{{ .Values.containerCommand }}] 
{{ end }}
```

The questions is how can i pass two arguments to "containerCommand" value.

Because when i want to these arguments to the helm, i got an error:

I got an error Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].command[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.command: got "array", expected "string"

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the collection using `range` operator, like following

```
{{ if .Values.containerCommand }}
      command: {{- range .Values.containerCommand }}
        - {{ . }} {{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

To learn details check [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

Comment: I got an error

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].command[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.command: got "array", expected "string"

Comment: Yes, im trying upgrade it.

Comment: can you add current deployed yaml? and what's in current command value

Comment: Deployed yaml here is. 

spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /app/out/appReport.js
        command:
        - node